# layoutmanager.FindFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition always returns -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview in my android project which displays media contents within each view. What I'm trying to achieve is that I'm able to play/pause media as I scroll up and down. I need to get the adapter position of the completely visible view. I'm doing something like this.

In my activity fragment I have this:

```
        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);

        adapter = new FeedAdapter(vid, userName, this.Context);

        feeditem.SetLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
        feeditem.SetAdapter(adapter);

        var onScrollListener = new XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener(Activity, layoutmanager, adapter);
```

The scroll listener event looks like this:

```
public override void OnScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
    {
        base.OnScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == (int)ScrollState.Idle)
        {
            layoutmanager = (LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.GetLayoutManager();

            int firstVisiblePosition = layoutmanager.FindFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            int visible = layoutmanager.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int last = layoutmanager.FindLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (firstVisiblePosition >= 0)
            {
                if (oldFocusedLayout != null)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(ctx, "Stop Video", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }


            }
            currentFocusedLayout = layoutmanager.FindViewByPosition(firstVisiblePosition);

            Toast.MakeText(ctx, "Play video", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            oldFocusedLayout = currentFocusedLayout;

        }
    }

        feeditem.AddOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
```

The issue is that the linearlayout manager method `FindFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` always returns -1 even when the view is completely visible. Other methods like `FindFirstVisibleItemPosition` and `FindLastVisibleItemPosition` gives the correct position of the view.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 5):

> layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

**FROM [DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())**

Returns the adapter position of the **FIRST FULLY VISIBLE** view. This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.

It mean that, at least one listitem view should be fully visible otherwise, it give -1 (NO_POSITION)

**FROM TESTING**

This will work and give correct position...

[image: Fully Visible ListItem View]

This won't work and give -1 (NO_POSITION), because two ListItem view is not fully visible.

[image]